Why the first matrix is not always psd but the second matrix is always psd?
I learned that one important motivation for the Newey-West covariance estimator is that naive estimator of the covariance matrix is not necessarily positive semidefinite(psd from now on) (see the reference links below, where the last link is the paper link of the Newey-West 1987 paper that proposes this HAC covariance estimator).
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newey%E2%80%93West_estimator
https://www.econometrics-with-r.org/15.4-hac-standard-errors.html
https://www.jstor.org/stable/1913610
Below is the paragraph from the paper presenting the naive estimator, which is not necessarily psd:

The following paragraph is the newey-west HAC estimator:

Comparing this two formulas, we could see that the newey-west HAC estimator merely added the weight $w(j,m)$ on the original estimator. Thus it seems that this weighting is key for making the new estimator $\widehat{S}_T$ psd. But there is one thing that confuses me here, in the highlighted part, the authors claim that the psd of matrix $\widehat{S}_T$  follows from the psd of sample autocovariance $\widehat{\Omega}_j$ (instead of the weighting). Since the sample autocovariance $\widehat{\Omega}_j$ is already there in the matrix $\widetilde{S}_T$ in equation (4), how could it not have guaranteed the psd of matrix $\widetilde{S}_T$ but only guaranteed the psd of the new estimator $\widehat{S}_T$? (what exactly is the role of weights $w(j,m)$ in making $\widehat{S}_T$ psd?)    Thanks in advance!
